# Complex join query with query builder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am trying to write a complex query with query builder and I need help(I am a complete noob in join queries) The situation is like this, I have a country table, a hotel table with country_id relationship, and promotions with hotel_id relationship.

So hotels have countries, and promotions have hotels. Now I need to find all promotions who belong to a a set of countries. To do that I need to check that the hotels they belong to are in those countries.

Anyway can someone help me build the query with query builder? I'll accept mysql queries as well.

Comment: You need promotions which belong to all countries in a set or any countries in a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up your relationships with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` in your entities and you've populated a desired Doctrine collection or array of IDs of countries into `$countries`:

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, h, p')
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Promotion', 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p.hotels', 'h')
    ->innerJoin('h.country', 'c')
    ->where('c IN (:countries)')
    ->setParameter('countries', $countries)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

The resulting SQL will end up being something similar to:

```
SELECT c.*, h.*, p.* FROM promotions p
    INNER JOIN hotels h ON p.hotel_id = h.id
    INNER JOIN country c ON h.country_id = c.id
    WHERE c.id IN (?)
```

Note that **this query will not work without defining your Doctrine entities appropriately.** Since you didn't provide your Entity configuration, I had to answer your question with assumptions. [Here's some more information on setting up your Database with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html), specifically [Entity Relationship mapping](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations)

Comment: My relationships are one way many to one. So hotels have many to one relationship with country and promotions have many to one relationship with hotels, but I do not have the other way relationship. So hotels have no idea who their promotions are and countries have no idea what hotels there are,

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi You need to make them bi-directional then.

Comment: I am wiser now and realize your answer was spot on ;)